# Discrete cosine Transform (DCT) in java

Tags: java, arrays, dct

This is the sourcecode DCT .. !!! unknown array of 4x4 DCT will be done by splitting the 4x4 array into several blocks past yyang 2x2 transformation on each block ... !!! I want to ask, how to display an array that has been done, but with size 4x4 transformation, and not the size of 2x2 .. !!! because it is only as a condition 2x2 to be transformed, once transformed restored to its original array size 4x4. please help...!!!

```
public class Main {
private static final int N = 4;
private static double[][] f = new double[4][4];
private static Random generator = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Generate random integers between 0 and 255
    int value;
    for (int x=0;x<N;x++) 
    {
        for (int y=0;y<N;y++) 
        {
          value = generator.nextInt(255);
          f[x][y] = value;
          System.out.print(f[x][y]+" ");
        }
         System.out.println();
    }




     DCT dctApplied = new DCT();
    double[][] F = dctApplied.applyDCT(f);
    System.out.println("From f to F");
    System.out.println("-----------");

        for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
          for (int j=0;j<2;j++) 
          {

         try {
             System.out.print(F[i][j]+" ");
             } 
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                System.out.println(e);
             }

         }
             System.out.println(" ");
        }

}
```

}

This is for the sourcecode DCT

```
public class DCT {
private static final int N = 2;
private static final int M = 2;

private double[] c = new double[N];

public DCT() 
{
      this.initializeCoefficients();
}

private void initializeCoefficients() 
{
    for (int i=1;i<N;i++) 
    {
        c[i]=1;
    }
    c[0]=1/Math.sqrt(2.0);
}

public double[][] applyDCT(double[][] f)
    {
     double[][] F = new double[4][4];  

    for (int row = 0; row < (f.length); row += 2) {
    for (int column = 0; column < f[0].length; column+=2) {
     for (int u=0;u<N;u++) 
     {
        for (int v=0;v<N;v++) 
         {
           double sum = 0.0;
           for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
           {
             for (int j=0;j<N;j++) 
             {
              f[i][j]=f[row+i][column+j];
               sum+=Math.cos(((2*i+1)/(2.0*N))*u*Math.PI)*Math.cos(((2*j+1)/(2.0*N))*v*Math.PI)*f[i][j];
             }
           }
               sum*=((2*c[u]*c[v])/Math.sqrt(M*N));
               F[u][v]=sum;
        }
    }
    }
     }
    return F;
}
```

}

display if the source code above is executed.
so this program as a 4x4 array F, then do DCT on F 4x4 4x4 array but by breaking into pieces the size of 2x2. so, 4x4 array will consist of 4 parts 2x2, then each part is done transformations and array F will be f. however, when displaying the array f, which appear only the red stripes !! there may be a mistake, so I please help...!
[image: eksekusi]

This is an example of an overview of the program that I want :
[image]

Comment: So you want to print the array returned from the function `applyDCT()`? To display matrix you use `\t` for tab in the rows and `\n` for new line at the end of the row.

Comment: during the process of DCT, 4x4 array split into 2x2 blocks in the DCT transformation ... !!! but I ask how to display an array of transformed back into a 4x4 array

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: for example in the picture

Comment: So this is what I understands: you intialise `F[][]` in `applyDCT` function as 4*4 array but your `u` & `v` always go from `0 to 2` and so `F[u][v] = sum;` will always update block 1 portion of `F[][]`. And so I think you should just change it to `F[u+row][v+column] = sum;`. You then print `F[][]` normally as suggested above,

Comment: that's right, but you try to look back on my question, I have to fix it, I hope you can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Change a little bit in your code:

In Main class:

Change the testing part of the `for` loop where you are printing `F[][]` to `i<4` (in place of `i<2`) and `j<4` (in place of `j<2`).

In DCT class:

Change `F[u][v] = sum;` to `F[u+row][v+column] = sum;`inside the `for` loops.

Comment: I just joined here, so I do not know how to mark your answer as the answer

Comment: See the tick mark on the left side of the answer. Click the tick mark corresponding to the answer. It will become green when selected.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple function that will print any 2 dimensional matrix:

```
    public void printMatrix(double[][] matrix) {
        int rows = matrix.length;
        int cols = matrix[0].length;

        String s = "";

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                s += matrix[row][col] + "\t";
            }

            s += "\n";
        }

        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

So you would call it like this:

`printMatrix(F);`

Comment: Why the down vote?  The OP asked "I want to ask, how to display an array that has been done, but with size 4x4 transformation, and not the size of 2x2" and the accepted answer still relies on numeric constants (int 4) which, while correct, is not as general as the answer I provided.